# Evaluate output of a background linux command with C++ or Bash/Shell Script

Tags: c++, linux, bash

**Question:** Using C++ or a bash/shell script, how can I evaluate output of a long running linux process?

**Example:**

```
root@example.com~# iw event
(This command will run until manually killed.) 
(It will output data that I will want to read and parse line by line.)
```

What is the most efficient way to evaluate the std output of this command when a new line is added to its buffer?

For example: iw event will output a line that says:

```
new station: 0e:0e:20:2d:20
```

I want to detect "new station" and run another command with the mac address. IE:

```
./myProgram -mac 0e:0e:20:2d:20
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking for the most efficient way, what ways can you imagine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the command as shown, all output will go to stdout and display on the terminal.  To capture the output you have a few options:

- Pipe the output to your monitor program, as in `iw events | yourmonitorprogram` which then reads stdin.  `iw` should probably be modified to use unbuffered output.
- Write the output of `iw` to a file and then use the same technique as the `tail -f` command to poll the file periodically
- Have `iw` write to a named pipe or socket and have your monitor program read from that pipe or socket.  This option requires modification to `iw`.

The simplest option is the first one

Comment: Line buffered output should be ok as well.